# Label text is being changed multiple times in function, but isn't updated on screen

Tags: swift

In my app, I need to have text displayed using a label.  A value is provided by the user, and it is used to determine the delay between each text change.  Each time the label updates, its text becomes the next item in my array.  When it is used in the app, though, the label changes to the last item in the array after a few seconds (delay time multiplied by amount of items in the array).  I also print the item, but that prints all of the items at once after a few seconds (the delay time multiplied by the amount of items in the array).  So, is there a way for the label to update after each change, instead of changing at the end?

The code that is causing problems:

```
    @IBAction func startEndTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

    var wordsPerMinVal:Double = 60.0/sliderValueBen

    for item in textEnterGo {
        delay(wordsPerMinVal){
            self.yourWordsLabel.text = item
            print(item)   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the way the event loop is used to update the UI, and how your code plugs into the loop.

When your code gets the control, screen rendering stops to let your code make any updates that it needs to make. Once your code returns, Cocoa analyzes the changes made inside your method, and updates the visuals accordingly.

This provides the key to solving your problem: Cocoa cannot see any changes until your method is over, including the `for` loop. That is why you see only the last update, while the intermediate updates go unnoticed.

In order to fix this problem you need to re-think the approach: rather than using a loop, make a method that keeps its state in a member variable. Call that method from the event handler, set the state for the first display, display the first item, set the timer to wake you up in `wordsPerMinVal`, and return. This would let the event loop render your changes. When the timer calls you back, change the visuals, set the timer again as needed, and return again. Continue until you are done going through the updates.