# How do I update a UILabel repeatedly and control the speed at which it changes?

Tags: swift, for-loop, uilabel

I'm creating an app that calculates a result and when the result is displayed, I'd like it to count very quickly from 0 up to the result, but slowly enough that you can see the numbers whizzing by as it counts.

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391365/label-text-is-being-changed-multiple-times-in-function-but-isnt-updated-on-scr) seems very close to what I'm looking for but involves managing state, which I can't figure out how to do.

I started with this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let calculator = CalculatorBrain(weightLifted: 0, repetitions: 0)

@IBOutlet weak var weightLifted: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repetitions: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var oneRepMax: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {
    let lift = Double(weightLifted.text!)
    let reps = Double(repetitions.text!)
    calculator.weightLifted = lift!
    calculator.repetitions = reps!
    let max = Int(calculator.calculateOneRepMax())
    for i in 0...max {
        oneRepMax.text = "\(i)" <-- I think this approach is where I'm going wrong
    }   
}
```

Here's the other class that goes with it:

```
class CalculatorBrain: NSObject {

var weightLifted: Double
var repetitions: Double
var oneRepMax: Double?

init(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: Double) {
    self.weightLifted = weightLifted
    self.repetitions = repetitions
 }

func calculateOneRepMax() -> Double {
    // Epley Method

    oneRepMax = self.weightLifted * (1 + (self.repetitions)/30)
    return oneRepMax!
 }
}
```

Following the advice in the other thread, I should get rid of the for loop and create a new method that keeps its state in a member variable. Then, call that method from the event handler, set the state for the first display, display the first item, do something, and return.

But since I want to see the oneRepMax.text value start at 0 and count up to the max value, I don't see how to do this without a loop somewhere. If I were to create a separate function to update the oneRepMax.text with something like this:

```
func updateCounter(max: Int) -> Int {
     for i in 1...max {
        return max <-- this will just return the max value after the loop stops running which is the same problem I already have
       }
    }
```

Any help for this newbie is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a loop like that, the text is probably going to update as quickly as the process can increment a number (extremely fast). If I understand your question correctly then you'll probably want to use a timer roughly similar to below

```
let timeInterval = 0.4 // how quickly you want the number to change

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

var counter: Int = 0
var max: Int = 0

func updateLabel(){
  if(counter == max){
    timer.invalidate()
  }
  // Increment counter and update label
}
```

Comment: This worked - thanks! The other thread I referred to said to keep state in a member variable of a new function. Is NSTimer essentially managing a state for me internally since it's a repeating timer?

Comment: Well the NSTimer is just the tool you use to delay your function (updateLabel). All it's actually doing is telling the processor to wait the specified timeInterval to run that function.You keep track of your counter and max outside of that function, so that you can tell the timer when it can finish firing. Your event handler would start the timer, keep track of the state (i.e. counter), and ultimately end the operation.

Comment: If that isn't clear then check out this dope analogy. Think of your program as a firework. Your event handler is the fuse, the NSTimer keeps all of the mortars inside firework from shooting all at once and lights the fireworks in a specified interval, and the box containing the mortars manages the order of the fireworks and ultimately when it's finished  firing (i.e. when it's out of mortars).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timer. In your callback set your label. You need to play with the interval to get what you want.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "yourCallback:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```